# Construct a variadic template of unsigned int recursively

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I need a tricky thing in a C++ 2011 code.
Currently, I have a metafunction of this kind :

```
template<unsigned int N, unsigned int M> 
static constexpr unsigned int myFunction()
```

This function can generate number based on `N` and `M`.

I would like to write a metafunction with input `N` and `M`, and that will recursively construct a variadic template by decrementing `M`. For example, by calling this function with `M = 3`, It will construct a variadic template called `List` equal to :

```
List... = myFunction<N, 3>, myFunction<N, 2>, myFunction<N, 1>, myFunction<N, 0>
```

How to do that (if it is possible of course) ?

Comment: it would be better if you tell the use case i.e how you're going to use it . also simply function name `myFunction<N, 3>` means nothing without parenthesis.A more elaborated example with use case would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably simplest to use an existing tuple pack generator:

```
// Idiomatic tuple pack generator using successor method
template<int... I> struct tuple_pack {
    using succ = tuple_pack<I..., sizeof...(I)>;
};
template<int N> struct make_tuple_pack {
    using type = typename make_tuple_pack<N - 1>::type::succ;
};
template<> struct make_tuple_pack<0> {
    using type = tuple_pack<>;
};
```

Now we can apply the tuple pack generator, delegating to an implementation function:

```
template<int N, int M, typename T> struct foo_impl {};
template<int N, int M, int... I> struct foo_impl<N, M, tuple_pack<I...>> {
    static void foo() {
        int arr[M] = { myFunction<N, M - I>()... };
    }
};
template<int N, int M> void foo() {
    foo_impl<N, M, typename make_tuple_pack<M>::type>::foo();
}
```

If you prefer function parameter inference to class template specialisation this could also be written as:

```
template<int N, int M, int... I> void foo_impl(tuple_pack<I...>) {
    int arr[M] = { myFunction<N, M - I>()... };
}
template<int N, int M> void foo() {
    foo_impl<N, M>(typename make_tuple_pack<M>::type{});
}
```

I had to specify the array size as `int arr[M]`; not sure whether that's required by the standard for pack expansion initializers or whether it's a bug in gcc; either way it's no big hassle.